# Найти расхождение в массивах

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите в решении проблемы, как найти расхождение в массивах и потом то, что не совпало из второго массива занести в третий массив. Т.е. суть такова, из БД я вытягиваю поля и помещаю их в массив №1, дальше с некого ресурса получаю строки и из этих строк формирую массив №2, и дальше мне нужно заполнить мою таблицу в БД уникальными строками из второго массива, а уникальные надо получить путем сравнения первого и второго массива, чтобы не было дублей, ну и третим массивом я буду делать вставку новых строк в таблицу БД.

Первый массив:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/d883e964f2ec11e2a6fd22000aeb11b7_5.jpg
    [1] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/1867744aee1711e2926822000a1f9c9b_5.jpg
    [2] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/bbb9a07ee98e11e2965422000a9f1599_5.jpg
    [3] => http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/9452e312250a11e3b66c22000ae80d1c_5.jpg
    [4] => http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/ec9b06e424e711e3a63622000a9e28ec_5.jpg
    [5] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/67fa6b54235811e38d4922000aa821c8_5.jpg
    [6] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/47a8598e227111e3858822000ab48269_5.jpg
    [7] => http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/4e854b4c222911e38bf022000a9f139a_5.jpg
    [8] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/7e278c56212611e3939222000a9f1385_5.jpg
    [9] => http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/499c77661ef211e3830722000a1f9d75_5.jpg
    [10] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/ec9724dc1d6911e38c3c22000a1fb85a_5.jpg 
)
```

Второй массив:

```
Array (
    [0] => http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/49300b18c50f11e2bcf322000aaa033b_5.jpg 
    [1] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/ece3bc14f5d411e29cc922000ae81e4d_5.jpg
    [2] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/317d0728207c11e39c6822000a1f9688_5.jpg
    [3] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/a78b72be1c5411e3bfbf22000a9f1935_5.jpg
    [4] => http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/6438c0cc276511e399d822000ab5c170_5.jpg
    [5] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/67fa6b54235811e38d4922000aa821c8_5.jpg
    [6] => http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/47a8598e227111e3858822000ab48269_5.jpg
)
```

Comment: тоесть если некоего значения из 2го массива нет в 1м то занести его в 3й?

Comment: Все, решилось, про array_diff() знал но не сразу вспомнил, сразу паника ))) Спасибо друзья, за помощь и напоминание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте справку для приличия - http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php

Там найдетё функцию `array_diff()` и еще много чего полезного.